# Checking Dataframe columns for negative values

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm new to python and used the following code to list all of the columns in my dataframe and identify which columns may contain null values:

`df.isnull().any()`

Is there similar code that to check for columns which may contain negative values? I was trying to insert `'<0'` into the above code but probably getting the syntax wrong and couldn't find any other answers on-line.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do:

```
s = df.min(axis=0)
s[s < 0]
```

This creates a Series containing the minimum values for each column and then shows only those which are less than zero.

Example output for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [-1, 2, 3], 'col3': [1, -2, 3]})

col2   -1
col3   -2
dtype: int64
```

If you really just want the column names, you can do:

```
list(s[s < 0].keys())
```

Which will give you:

```
['col2', 'col3']
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I see how defining the 's' variable was what I was missing, I also wanted the column names so thanks for that option as well.